# it's a recursion problem that prints subsets of an array

Tags: python, class, recursion, arraylist, methods

```
class sub: 
  def f1(self,s1): 
    return self.f2([ ], (s1)) 

  def f2(self,curr,s1): 
    if s1: 
      return self.f2(curr,s1[1:]) + self.f2(curr + [s1[0]], s1[1:]) 
    return [curr] 

a=[]
n=int(input("enter a number:")) 

for i in range(0,n): 
  b=int(input("enter element:")) 
  a.append(b) 
  print("subset:") 
  print(sub().f1(a))
```

what I don't understand is how the method f2 works and whats the process behind this is

what I don't understand is how the method f2 works and whats the process behind this is
also it would be very much appriciated if someone can explain it with the help of a diagram. thank you in advance!

Comment: class sub:
    def f1(self,s1):
        return self.f2([ ], (s1))
    def f2(self,curr,s1):
        if s1:
            return self.f2(curr,s1[1:]) + self.f2(curr + [s1[0]], s1[1:])
        return [curr]
a=[]
n=int(input("enter a number:"))
for i in range(0,n):
    b=int(input("enter element:"))
    a.append(b)  
print("subset:")
print(sub().f1(a))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have to understand that `f2(curr, s1)` is supposed to be "the list of all subsets of `s1`, but each of them prepended with `curr`".

You can verify that it works on a few examples:

- `f2('xyz', 'abc')` is `['xyz', 'xyzc', 'xyzb', 'xyzbc', 'xyza', 'xyzac', 'xyzab', 'xyzabc']`;
- `f2(c, '')` is just `[c]`, for any `c`.

In case `s1` is not empty, then the return value `f2(curr,s1[1:]) + f2(curr + [s1[0]], s1[1:])` is a list made of two halves:

- the first half `f2(curr,s1[1:])`;
- the second half `f2(curr + [s1[0]], s1[1:])`.

The first half is the list of all subsets of `s1[1:]`, each of them prepended with `curr`. Note that the subsets of `s1[1:]` are exactly the subsets of `s1` that do not contain `s[0]`.

The second half is the list of all subsets of `s1[1:]`, each of them prepended by `curr` and by `s[0]`. Note that "all subsets of `s1[1:]`, prepended by `s[0]`" is exactly the same as "all subsets of `s1` that contain `s[0]`.

In other words, the line of code :

```py
return self.f2(curr,s1[1:]) + self.f2(curr + [s1[0]], s1[1:])
```

can be read as:

> The list of all subsets of `s1` consists in two halves: first the list of subsets that do not contain `s[0]`, then the list of subsets that do contain `s[0]`.

Those two halves are computed using recursion.